# Update TeXstudio portable and keep settings

Tags: texstudio, updating

I updated TeXstudio portable 2.6.6 to 2.8.2 by copying the content of the `zip`-file into the existing directory. Unfortunately, all settings, macros etc. were gone when starting the new TeXstudio. How can I update TeXstudio portable without loosing the settings, macros etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the `texstudio.ini` solves the problem. Due to the fact that the `.zip` file contains an empty `.ini` file, I ran into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question just today, and the solution is now slightly different. You can still use the `texstudio.ini` file. Alternatively, you can choose "Save Profile..." in your old version, then "Load Profile..." in the updated version, under "Options".

> [image]

Depending on how you updated, this may not transfer the *macros*, though.

- If you *overwrote* your previous portable folder, then your macros probably remained.
- If you simply renamed/deleted your old portable folder, and use the newly extracted one, then the macros won't be there.

To get the macros,, there is a folder in `/config` called `macros`. Simply copy and paste that folder into your new `/config` folder.